# DWH not a Star-Schema not a Snow flake not a E-R

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse, star-schema, snowflake-schema

I m aware aboud litterature/Theorie  for datawarehouse-architecture and how should be design.
The Bill-Imon E-R 3NF or the Kimball Star-Schema/Snow - flake Schema.

The problem come when i currently work in a DWH and it have no either any of these Schema, it is composed for 3 big Fact Tables around each of them are a lot of dimension Tables.(2 of 3 big Tables are conected)
[image]

So what kind of Schema its that ?

Thanks in Advance , Enrique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [galaxy schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fact_constellation).

Comment: "Galaxy" is more of a nick-name, but it is accurate. It represents a set of fact tables joined by conformed dimensions. This is the ideal model for a dimensional data warehouse. WARNING: There is a potential error in the picture, in that T1 appears directly joined to T3. This should never happen, fact should only join through a dimension. Unless the join columns are a degenerate dimension (no associated dimension data) there should be a dimension table in between.

Comment: Hi  @RonDunn  I looked again the model of the DWH in the Bank and of course is not exactly how I painted, but I have to tell you that T1 is conected with T2 and T3 directly and indirect conected (throw dimension Tables in the  middle). I m relative new in DWH but I hope they new what they do. So mybe it´s "the join columns are a degenerate dimension (no associated dimension data)".
Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If you were viewing the schema for a specific event (fact), you'd be looking at a star schema.

In the diagram you provided, you've pulled back to a larger view and can see multiple star schemas as well as how the events can be related.  This can be considered a constellation (collection of related stars, possibly a single module of a larger solution) or a galaxy (all of the star schemas in a solution, even if there is no relation between the stars).

However, I'd still describe your solution as using a star schema as the design pattern conversation normally refers to the event level, and the star pattern implies constellation/galaxy at a higher level.